# Attaching text to screenshot taken programatically

Tags: android, webview

I need to save the content of a webview as image for making it easier for sharing.

I managed to save the content of the webview as image (though I have to goto landscape mode for making the image smaller in height - I can't get it within the portrait!) but I need to attach some text and a watermark image to the bottom of the saved screenshot of webview.

Can any one help me to do so?

My code

```
if (webContentHeight <= 0) webContentHeight = wbContent.getContentHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(wbContent.getWidth(), (int) (webContentHeight * 1.5), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);



        wbContent.layout(0, 0, wbContent.getLayoutParams().width, wbContent.getLayoutParams().height);
        wbContent.draw(canvas);



        File imgDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "imgDir");
        if (!imgDir.exists()) imgDir.mkdirs();

        File imagePath = new File(imgDir, "Item_" +
                new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss").format(new Date()) + ".png");

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*"));

            if (Utils.IsNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext()))
                new AsyncTsk_GrabContent().execute();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't save news as image. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't save news as image. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't save news as image. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } finally {
            if (Orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_USER);
            if (pgDialog != null) {
                pgDialog.dismiss();
                pgDialog = null;
            }
        }
```

I tired this but can't meet the requirement :

```
 canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(16);
    canvas.drawText("My Text", 10, 10, paint);
    wbContent.draw(canvas);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing your text at (10,10), then drawing your wbContent at (0,0), you are drawing over your text. Either move the text down past 2/3 of the height of the canvas (as you seem to be intentionally making your canvas 1.5x the height of wbContent), or simply draw the text after drawing the wbContent.

Comment: I tried adding the Text after drawing the web content. But the text doesn't appear.

Can you please indicate where I should place the second content? I tried like these 

1 : 
    wbContent.layout(0, 0, wbContent.getLayoutParams().width,
    wbContent.getLayoutParams().height);wbContent.draw(canvas);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(16);
canvas.drawText("My Text", 10, 10, paint);
wbContent.draw(canvas);

Comment: Why do you draw the wbContent twice? The above code lays out the content, draws the page to the canvas, draws the text to the canvas, then draws the page to the canvas again.

Comment: Will you please help me by giving me a piece of code? I lost more than a week in this :-(